# Invoking curried function

Tags: scala

Below is an implementation of a curried function :

```
scala> def multiply(x: Int, y: Int) = x * y
multiply: (x: Int, y: Int)Int

scala> def multiplyCurried = (multiply _).curried
multiplyCurried: Int => (Int => Int)
```

When I a attempt to implement multiplyCurried I receive exception :

```
<console>:10: error: missing parameter type
              multiplyCurried(a => b => a * b)
```

What is correct implementation to invoke multiplyCurried ?

Comment: What do you want to use it for? Can you provide more details?

Comment: I think @blue-sky wants to find out how to invoke a curried function

Comment: @VictorMoroz this is just to understand how to invoke the function, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Wikipedia: [Currying](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying) is the technique of translating the evaluation of a function that takes multiple arguments (or a tuple of arguments) into evaluating a sequence of functions, each with a single argument (partial application)

```
def multiply(x: Int, y: Int) = x * y          //> multiply: (x: Int, y: Int)Int

def multiplyCurried = (multiply _).curried    //> multiplyCurried: => Int => (Int => Int)

def multiplyCurried2(x: Int)(y: Int) = x * y  //> multiplyCurried2: (x: Int)(y: Int)Int

def multiplyCurried3(x:Int) = (y:Int) => x * y //> multiplyCurried3: (x: Int)Int => Int

def multiplyCurried4 = multiplyCurried2 _ //> multiplyCurried4: => Int => (Int => Int)

multiply(1, 2)                                //> res1: Int = 2
multiplyCurried(1)(2)                         //> res2: Int = 2
multiplyCurried2(1)(2)                        //> res3: Int = 2
multiplyCurried3(1)(2)                        //> res4: Int = 2
```

`multiplyCurried2` is just syntactic sugar for `multiplyCurried3`.

As Victor correctly points out in the comments, `multiplyCurried` and `multiplyCurried2` are actually not the same. The implementation of `multiplyCurried4` contains the recipe to turn `multiplyCurried2` into a function which is basically equal to `multiplyCurried`.

What's so nice about currying is partial application:

```
val m = multiplyCurried(1)                    //> m  : Int => Int = <function1>
m(2)                                           //> res5: Int = 2
val m2 = multiplyCurried2(1)_                 //> m  : Int => Int = <function1>
m2(2) 

                                    //> res6: Int = 2
```

Comment: Technically speaking `multiplyCurried` and `multiplyCurried2` are different objects, one is a `<function1>`, another one is a method. Besides try `multiplyCurried2(1)`, you will get an error. Multiple parameter lists are not really a currying but type inference tool.

Comment: No, they're not and you can clearly see it looking at type: `//> multiplyCurried2: (x: Int)(y: Int)Int`. Besides the very name _lists_ imply zero or _more_ arguments (two is more too) and they're often used as such. Did you try to call `multiplyCurried2(1)`?